# MySQL: Dupe Error on UPDATE

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I've got a script running this update:

```
UPDATE `Cq_Item` 
SET     `rfq_item_id` = '9',
    `value` = 'No Bid',
    `datetime_created` = '2012-10-23T20:54:42+00:00',
    `id` = '101' 
WHERE `id` = '101'
```

Against this table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cq_item` (
  `id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rfq_item_id` mediumint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `product_id_quoted` mediumint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `quantity` mediumint(6) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `value` float(10,4) NOT NULL,
  `datetime_created` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `rfq_item_id` (`rfq_item_id`,`product_id_quoted`,`quantity`,`value`),
  KEY `product_id` (`product_id_quoted`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=102 ;
```

and it's throwing this error:

> 1062 - Duplicate entry '9-321742-1-0.0000' for key 'rfq_item_id'

Granted, i'm no SQL guru, but throwing a dupe error on an `update` seems a little less than intuitive to me.
I understand why such an error would get thrown on an `INSERT`, but I can use some help figuring out what i'm doing wrong to get that on this `UPDATE` :)

Comment: Just from the description of your error, it seems very obvious to me that you have another record with the same values in the fields included in the index `rfq_item_id`. Check your data... if you have an entry with the same data that you are trying to update, then you won't be able to perform the update (since it would violet the unique key rule). By the way, you don't need to set `id` again... it's value doesn't change

Comment: @Barranka it seems very obvious to me, too, that there is already a record which matches those unique constraints ... Thank goodness for people like @mike-brant who can help by sharing additional information ... (BTW, you are right that the `id` field isn't needed for the sql, but the business logic depends on it, so i'll make soem time to dig into that and see what can be done.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An update actually performs two separate operations (when conditions are met of course), a DELETE and then an INSERT.  You probably need to make sure that your UPDATE is not causing the row with id = 101 to violate your unique key that is already in place for another row.

So say you had two rows like this before attempting the update

```
id   |   rfq_item_id |   product_id_quoted  | quantity | value   | datetime_creates
100  |   9           |   9                  |    1     | 0.0000  | <some datetime>
101  |   10          |   9                  |    1     | 0.0000  | <some datetime>
```

Your UPDATE would throw the exact error you are seeing upon execution, because the rfq_item_id/product_id_quoted/quantity/value unique key would be the same.

I would guess your problem is related to trying to set a string value of "No Bid" on the field `value` which is defined as a float.  You thus will get a `0.0000` value in the update.

Also as mentioned in comment to original question,  it is generally considered to be bad SQL practice to try to "set" the value of the primary key that you are using in the WHERE clause of an UPDATE statement.  That is unless to really have a reason to change the primary key as part of the update.

Comment: Perfect answer ... Thank you!  I hadn't realized that an `UPDATE` was actually a two step process.  The enlightenment is much appreciated :D ... Also, when I get a chance, I'll look at the biz logic that I'm working with and extend it to exclude the PK from the update.

Answer (score 0):

your table structure says that rfq_item_id is unique key. and the value you are trying too set in update query is already in the table. So, it is not allowing you to update query with `rfq_item_id` = '9'.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your table description, you have a `unique key`:

```
UNIQUE KEY `rfq_item_id` (`rfq_item_id`,`product_id_quoted`,`quantity`,`value`)
```

You are attempting to perform an `UPDATE` with values that already meet the criteria of your `UNIQUE KEY`.

You already have a record with `rfq_item_id = '9'` and `value = 'No Bid'`, the values for the other two columns in the unique key also already match the values in `id = '101'`